Arch Linux installation inaccessible after BIOS update
I have an Arch Linux installation done via archinstall. It's set up to work with secure boot (I followed the "Unified Extensible Firmware Interface/Secure Boot" guide on the Arch Wiki using the "3.1.3 Assisted process with sbctl" method to set that up).
This is how my disk setup looks like:
├─ nvme0n1               <-- This is my Windows drive
│  ├─ nvme0n1p1 (16M)
│  └─ nvme0n1p2 (1.8T)   
└─ nvme1n1               <-- This is my Linux drive
   ├─ nvme1n1p1 (512M)   <-- /boot  EFI system 
   ├─ nvme1n1p2 (20G)    <-- /
   └─ nvme1n1p3 (911G)   <-- /home

This is how my /boot/EFI folder looks like:
└─ /boot/EFI
   ├─ BOOT
   │  └─ BOOTX64.EFI
   ├─ Linux
   │  └─ <empty>
   ├─ Microsoft
   │  ├─ Boot
   │  └─ Recovery
   └─ systemd
      └─ systemd-bootx64.efi

I only use Windows for games and I don't like having to pick an OS on the boot manager every time I start the computer, so I manually change the boot order to boot to Windows on the weekends and change it back to Linux afterwards. But after a firmware update on my motherboard (an MSI PRO Z690-A DDR4, now on firmware version 7D25v1J) I don't see the option to my Linux installation anymore.

Doing some research, I found people recommending reinstalling the boot manager, but I'm not too sure this is the way to go in my case. I'm trying to avoid it because 1) I don't know if it will mess my secure boot set up, and 2) Running bootctl status displays:

So I'm thinking this may be something that can or needs to be resolved from the UEFI software. But I don't know what I should do in that case.
I have tried chrooting the installation and running bootctl update hoping the problem might just fix itself, but that didn't work.
Now I'm trying to understand what happened after the firmware update (what changes were made and where) and if this is something I need to deal with on the UEFI side or the boot manager side. I'm still new to Arch and how the whole boot process works, and I honestly just don't know enough to figure out how to proceed from here. Any guidance is appreciated.
PS: I'm sorry about the screen pictures, but I don't have anything handy to capture the screen right now.


Doing some research, I found people recommending reinstalling the boot manager, but I'm not too sure this is the way to go in my case. I'm trying to avoid it because 1) I don't know if it will mess my secure boot set up, and 2) Running bootctl status displays:

Creating this entry is part of (re)installing the boot manager. EFI doesn't automatically discover operating systems from files – it requires each OS entry to be separately created in the mainboard's NVRAM (i.e. the "CMOS memory" where firmware settings are kept).
The two exceptions to this are 1) the EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI file, which acts as the "default" bootloader when no entries are present, or when you ask the firmware to boot a whole disk (like in the BIOS days), and 2) some manufacturers trying to be helpful and detecting Windows specifically, so that if you clear the firmware settings you automatically get a Windows entry (but generally nothing else).
So if you run bootctl install it will indeed re-create the "Linux Boot Manager" NVRAM boot entry after it has re-copied all of its files to the EFI partition, and the same is done by grub-install or bcdboot.exe. If you have manually signed those files for Secure Boot, re-run sbctl sign to sign them again.
The other option is to use efibootmgr to create the boot entry by hand:
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme1n1 -p 1 -l '\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi' -L "Gentoo"

...as well as adding it to the "boot order" using efibootmgr --bootorder 000x,000y.

I only use Windows for games and I don't like having to pick an OS on the boot manager every time I start the computer, so I manually change the boot order to boot to Windows on the weekends and change it back to Linux afterwards.

This is a good place to use another EFI feature – the "BootNext" variable, which lets you reboot from Linux straight into Windows without directly interacting with the boot manager (EFI or any other). See older thread.
